# Creating a gate which have multiple register as an input

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-operation

I'm trying to create a new gate in qiskit which the input is multiple register but the program output an error that says:

```
'The amount of qubit(1)/clbit(0) arguments does not match the gate expectation (13).'
```

here is my code :

```
def adder():
    x=QuantumRegister(n)
    y=QuantumRegister(n+1)
    A=QuantumRegister(n)
    qc=QuantumCircuit(x,y,A)
    for i in range(n-1):
        qc.append(carry(),[A[i],x[i],y[i],A[i+1]])
    qc.append(carry(),[A[n-1],x[n-1],y[n-1],y[n]])
    qc.cx(x[n-1],y[n-1])
    qc.append(circ_sum(),[A[n-1],x[n-1],y[n-1]])
    for i in range(n-2,-1,-1):
        qc.append(invcarry(),[A[i],x[i],y[i],A[i+1]])
        qc.append(circ_sum(),[A[i],x[i],y[i]])
    qc=qc.to_gate()
    qc.name = "adder"
    return qc
```

this is where I try to called the gate but resulting an error :

```
x=QuantumRegister(n,'x')
y=QuantumRegister(n+1,'y')
A=QuantumRegister(n,'dump')
nqc=QuantumCircuit(x,y,A)
nqc.append(adder(),[x[:]+y[:]+A[:]])
```

I have count the number of qubit it's exactly same, can someone point out why it's giving me this error? and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the call of the function just remove the squar bracket since it already in  tuple

```
nqc.append(adder(),x[:]+y[:]+A[:])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I disagree.  This answer is perfectly clear.  There is a typo in the code and Taufiq succinctly provided the correction.

Comment: STOP USING BOTS!